# function somersD returns NaN

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
> dput(master_credit)
structure(c(10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 11, 11, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 
12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 12, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12, 11, 12, 12, 14, 13, 12, 13, 13, 
14, 13, 13, 12, 25, 26, 3, 21, 5, 9, 43, 15, 2, 6, 4, 27, 44, 
1, 10, 31, 16, 12, 37, 7, 23, 54, 18, 19, 20, 14, 35, 52, 36, 
32, 29, 50, 51, 30, 42, 24, 17, 63, 8, 62, 38, 34, 33, 49, 59, 
58, 57, 60, 28, 61, 40, 41, 22, 11, 47, 13, 48, 45, 46, 65, 64, 
53, 39, 56, 55), .Dim = c(65L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("master", 
"credit")))
```

on which I am running the code:

```
    library(InformationValue)
    > somersD(master_credit[,"master"], master_credit[,"credit"])
    [1] NaN
```

why does it return NaN?

Comment: Vignettes say that `somersD` function *The actual binary flags for the response variable. It can take a numeric vector
containing values of either 1 or 0, where 1 represents the ’Good’ or ’Events’
while 0 represents ’Bad’ or ’Non-Events’*

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `somersD` says `somersD(actuals, predictedScores)`, where `actuals` are binary flags which are either 1 or 0.

> actuals: The actual binary flags for the response variable. It can take a numeric vector containing values of either 1 or 0, where 1 represents the 'Good' or 'Events' while 0 represents 'Bad' or 'Non-Events'.

Internally while calculating Somers D statistics, `somersD` function tries to find the number of rows containing, `1` and `0` in `actuals` column. This count is used in division. And since in your dataframe there is no such row, so you are basically dividing by zero, hence it returns `NaN`.

Comment: This seems to be the answer. If so, please mark it as the answer. ;)